# Getting Started on Heroku with Node.js

Tags: heroku

I am an extreme beginner when it comes to working with Heroku/programming. I am trying to follow the instructions for getting started on Heroku and deploying a Node.js app. Everything seems to be working fine up to the point where I need to modify the app (link below).

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#push-local-changes

I edited my index.js file with the recommended code but when I test locally and visit the application I get the following:

Cannot GET /cool

Is there a step that I am missing?

Here is the code from my index.js file:

```
const cool = require('cool-ascii-faces')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
  .get('/cool', (req, res) => res.send(cool()))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Is there a step that I am missing?" Maybe, but we can't see any of your code so it's impossible to say for sure. Please read [ask].

Comment: That would be helpful wouldn't it! Apologies, this is my first time. I just added the code from my index.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've actually modified the actual index.js file that runs on your local instance (you may have also cloned the repo with NetBeans/other elsewhere)